# Admob UMPConsentForm loadAndPresentIfRequired method not found even I have the latest version

Tags: ios, swift, admob, gdprconsentform

Google mentioned to call "In case you missed it, we announced new consent management platform requirements for serving ads in the EEA and UK. Beginning January 16, 2024, Google will require all publishers to use a Google-certified consent management platform (CMP) when serving ads to users in the European Economic Area or the UK."

but it's giving me error

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmwXK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy6wf.png)

I tried documenntation and I was expecting it to run with no error

Comment: Please do not post images of text. The actual text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the SDK by downloading the zip from the documentation, try to delete it from the project and add it with the help of Swift Package Manager. It worked for me.

Here's the URL of the repository:

```
https://github.com/googleads/swift-package-manager-google-user-messaging-platform.git
```